# show subtitle on media player

Tags: c#, winforms

I have used a Windows Media Player COM component in a winform app.
But the subtitle can not display on it.

subtitle and video are in the same folder, if just open the wmv file by media player it can be shown correctly. I really got puzzled by this embedded COM component .

is there any one know this case?

Answer (score 0):

Subtitles are displayed (sometimes) by directvoxsub, a directshow plugin that should automatically load when used in media player and media player components.  Do you have it installed and configured properly?